# Try except pass function not continuing

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, ftp, try-catch

So I need help passing my exception and continuing with the rest of my script. The short background story is I need to get the first 400kb of a file on a ftp server, that has the +CONTENTS folder I need. I expect an error for the end of file missing because I am terminating the ftp connection before the file completes. In my testing I can terminate the ftp connection but it hangs after the {print "7"} saying:

> gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
>   tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

So, the script does not continue to the next try statement. My code is currently as follows, any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file_to_write:
        print '1'

        def callback(chunk):
            print '2'
            file_to_write.write(chunk)
            print '3'
            if os.path.isfile(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 400000:
                print os.path.getsize(filename), "FILE SIZE"
                subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-xvf', filename, '+CONTENTS'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                print "4"
                try:
                    if os.path.isfile('+CONTENTS'):
                        last_size = []
                        content_size = os.path.getsize('+CONTENTS')
                        cnt_sz = content_size
                        last_size.append(cnt_sz)
                        print "5", last_size
                        print "6", cnt_sz
                        if max(last_size) == content_size:
                            print "7"
                            ftp.quit()
                except EnvironmentError:
                    pass
            else:
                print 'continuing'
                # time.sleep(.1)

        ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % filename, callback, 4096)
except EOFError, e:
    print e
    pass
```

Comment: `file_to_write.close()` in the except-clause is pointless since you opened the file using the with-statement.  The point of opening a file that way is to handle closing it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I will take that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work like this, the ftp.quit is still causing me errors in this portion so I will quit later in the script.

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file_to_write:
        print '1'
        last_size = 0

        def callback(chunk):
            global last_size
            if last_size is None:
                last_size = 0
            print '2'
            file_to_write.write(chunk)
            print '3'
            if os.path.isfile(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 400000:
                print os.path.getsize(filename), "FILE SIZE"
                subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-xvf', filename, '+CONTENTS'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                print "4"
                try:
                    if os.path.isfile('+CONTENTS'):
                        content_size = os.path.getsize('+CONTENTS')
                        print "5", last_size
                        print "6", content_size
                        if last_size == content_size:
                            print "7"
                            raise Exception
                        last_size = content_size
                except EnvironmentError:
                    pass
            else:
                print 'continuing'

        ftp.retrbinary("RETR %s" % filename, callback, 4096)
except:
    pass
```